# Calculating definite integral of array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral

I need to compute the definite integral of an equation represented by an array of its y-values and an array of its x-values.

I was originally going to use np.trapz, but then I couldn't specify the bin size I wanted to integrate over, so I wrote my own function that takes in the x-array, y-array, lower and upper bounds of integration, and step/bin size.

```py
def integrate(fx, fy, lower_bound, upper_bound, step):

    # sort it, and then trim off any elements that are out of bounds
    output_x = np.sort(fx)
    output_x = output_x[lower_bound : upper_bound]

    output_y = np.zeros(len(output_x))

    # loop over every x value in output_x
    for i in range(len(output_x)):
        for j in range(len(output_y)):
            # interpolate the values
            interpolated = np.interp(output_x[i], fx, fy)
            # calculate integral
            q = (interpolated[j] - interpolated[j-1]) * step
            result = np.sum(q)


    return (result)


array_x = np.arange(0,10,.2)
array_y = np.sqrt(array_x)

integrate(array_x, array_y, .125, 8, .25)
```

My expected output is just the value of the definite integral. I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 ################ Plutonium 239
>         2 
>   ----> 3 integrate(mult_x2, mult_y2, .125, 8, .25)
>
> in integrate(fx, fy, lower_bound, upper_bound, step)
>         7     # we sort it, and then trim off any elements that are out of bounds
>         8     output_x = np.sort(fx)
>   ----> 9     output_x = output_x[lower_bound : upper_bound]
>        10 
>        11     output_y = np.zeros(len(output_x))
>
> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Comment: `lower_bound` is `0.125`, which is an invalid index.

Comment: Please post a runnable code. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies, edited so there are two arrays defined. How could I rewrite the definition with the lower bound and upper bound values used properly to calculate the integral?

Comment: The short answer is that your upper and lower bounds are coordinates, which don't necessarily line up with indices for the actual points you have. You'll have to find a way to go from a coordinate to a nearest index and vice-versa.